# Solve the inequality $ 2 \cdot \arccos(x^{2}-4)\geq π $

Tags: calculus, inequality

my name is Agapita and I have a question about this inequality:

$$ 2 \cdot \arccos(x^{2}-4)\geq \pi $$
What I have done so far is:

$$ \arccos(x^{2}-4)\geq \frac{\pi}{2} $$

$$ x^{2}-4\geq  \arccos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) $$

$$ x^{2}-4\geq 0$$

$$ x^{2}\geq 4$$

$$x\geq \sqrt{4} $$

$$ x\geq2  $$ $$\text{and}$$ $$ x\geq-2  $$

So:

$x  = {]} {-\infty}, -2] \cup [2, \infty[$

But the actual solution to this problem is:
$[-2, -\sqrt{3}] \cup [\sqrt{3},2]$

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. The function $\arccos$ is defined in $[-1,1]$ and it strictly decreases from $\pi$ to $0$.
Hence the inequality
$$\arccos(x^{2}-4)\geq \frac{\pi}{2}$$
is equivalent to
$$-1=\cos(\pi)\leq  x^{2}-4\leq \cos(\pi/2)=0$$
that is
$$3\leq  x^{2}\leq 4.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\arccos(x^2-4)\ge \frac{\pi}{2}$ is equivalent to $-1\le x^2-4 \le 0$. Also note that $x^2\le 4$ is equivalent to $|x|\le 2$